# How to make wait the 1 method to finish other in Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, wait

In asp.net website, i need to submit the some fields to insert into database. OnclientClick event i have javascript method to validate the input, it method return false in case validation failed and true in case validation success. If it return true then server side event process ahead to insert the data.

My problem is in javascript main validation method it call server side method through ajax to get some data in order to validate the form. Main javascript method dont wait of server side call and it process move ahead, that means i am not able to validate that method and it go ahead and make postback.

```
function ValidateInput()
{
if(1 == 2)
{
return false;
}
// other logic to validate
ServiceSideCalltoValidate();
// It dont wait of above method and make the postback
}
```

In other words i need to implement the logic so that 1 javascript method should wait to finish the call of another javascript.

Comment: Well , you can call a method (a method which validates) and use a return value. If the returned value is true , you can make the AJAX call.

Comment: @harsha, I am doing same but it don't wait of the ajax call and proceed, result is that it make post back without validating the ajax call return value

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript function calls AJAX to validate the data and every AJAX call complete then it will return value. So what you need to do it, return some value from AJAX call and if its true then after you can call server size click event.

Comment: Ajax server side call also validate the data and return status, if it is success then javascript method return true and post back would proceed, if status is false then no postback and return false. But it dont wait of ajax call